# How can I apply paging to a non-list type

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null, int page = 1)
{
            var racks = repository.AllFindRacks(searchTerm).OrderBy(a=>a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, 5) ;

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                return PartialView("_RackTable", racks);
            }
            return View(racks);
}
```

which calls the following repository method:-

```
public RackJoinList AllFindRacks(string q)
{
            RackJoinList rjlist = new RackJoinList();
            var racks = from rack in tms.TMSRacks.Where(a => a.Technology.Tag.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()) || (q == null))

                  select rack;

            rjlist.Racks = racks.ToList();
            var resources = from resource in entities.Resources
                            join c in rjlist.Racks
                            on resource.RESOURCEID equals c.Technology.IT360ID
                            select resource;
            rjlist.Resources = resources;

            return rjlist;
}
```

and the `RackJoinList` view model is :-

```
public class RackJoinList
{
        public IEnumerable<TMSRack> Racks { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
}
```

but as the repository method return single object, I am unable to apply orderby and paging to it. Can anyone advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark but what about this:

```
RackJoinList list = repository.AllFindRacks(searchTerm);
list.Racks = list.Racks.OrderBy(a=>a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, 5);
```

AllFindRacks returns one object, but that one object has two IEnumerable collections in it, Racks and Resources.  I'm assuming you want to call OrderBy on Racks here.

**Edit Explanation:**

What I did was this;

Store the RackJoinList object, because this will be sent off elsewhere later.

Alter the RackJoinList object's Racks collection.

Send off the RackJoinList object with the altered Racks collection.

*Caveat:*  I'm unsure how ToPagedList works.  Is there documentation somewhere on it?  I tried Google to no avail.

**Edit #2:**

Here's how I would restructure it based on the source of PagedList.  The caveat here is that I can't compile this so I don't know if `PagedList<TMSRack>` is the right type.  Let this be known as a case where writing documentation using `var` is annoying!

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null, int page = 1)
{
    RackJoinList list = repository.AllFindRacks(searchTerm);
    list.PagedRacks = list.Racks.OrderBy(a=>a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, 5);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_RackTable", racks);
    }

    return View(list);
}

public class RackJoinList
{
    public IEnumerable<TMSRack> Racks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
    public PagedList<TMSRack> PagedRacks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in this way i will be passing .Rack to my view . but i need to pass RackJoinList.

Comment: @johnG I made an edit, but I probably need to do another iteration on it.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @RyanWH PagedList is a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/)  Here is the [GitHub page](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Comment: @cadrell0 Thanks for that, I feel like Google failed me on this one!

Comment: @johnG I made an update after seeing the documentation for ToPagedList.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but doing so will raise the following exception "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TMS.ViewModels.RackJoinList', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[TMS.ViewModels.RackJoinList]'. " on the view which is expecting IPagedList<TMS.ViewModels.RackJoinList>.

Comment: @johnG Does that break on a line in the code you've shown or somewhere else?  It might be that you need to make a collection of type `PagedList<RackJoinList>` but that's a completely wild guess on my part.

Comment: this will raise an exception on the view. so what other approaches i can take?

Comment: @johnG Sorry, but I can't think of a solution.  It's hard to guess without seeing the bigger picture.  It _sounds_ like you want a `PagedList<RackJoinList>` declared in the same class as your `Index` function, and to return a page of that `PagedList`.